# How to get position of image in PowerPoint from centimeters to points with VBA

Tags: vba, position, powerpoint

So I have an image on a slide and I need to get the position of said image in points, but I only know its position in centimeters. I need the points so that I can place another image directly over it with the following VBA code:

```
Set myImageBox = mySlide.Shapes.AddPicture(ActivePresentation.Path & "\X.png", False, True, xPos, yPos, -1, -1)
```

Where `xPos` and `yPos` are the coordinates of the image I am trying to overlay. I am a bit of a novice with VBA as far as PPT is concerned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the location from the existing object before you set the next one.

You can use `.Left` for X

and `.Top` for Y

Example:

```
xPos = yourShape.Left
yPos = yourShape.Top
```

Note:
You will need to find the shape and assign it to an `Object` named `yourShape` for the example code to work.

Comment: .GetLeft and .GetTop are Publisher methods, not PowerPoint.

Answer (score -1):

Office measurements in the user interface are in points by default. There's no conversion, just set xPos and yPos to the number of points.

However, if the object you're trying to align to has been positioned by hand, there will probably still be a slight misalignment. This is because Office's internal measurements are mostly in EMUs (360,000 EMUs equal 1 cm, 12,7000 EMUs equal 1 point). You can't set or get VBA measurements in EMUs, and points are considerably less accurate.

To get an exact match, you would have to set both objects to the same position programmatically.